# <PostLink> <Link> tag in NextJs with Typescript is not showing any PostLink as Tutorial showed

Tags: typescript, next.js

/  tags are not working. Nothing was shown after compiling unlike the tutorial.

I was following the tutorial on Nextjs.org, and I also uses the typescript version with create-next-app typescript. After struggling with a bunch of types, I finally able to compile however is see a blank component. 
And when I look at the console, it said 
index.js:1 Warning: the 'url' property is deprecated. https://err.sh/zeit/next.js/url-deprecated

I clicked the link, I have followed the instructions even download the codemod, nothing happened, does anyone know what I should do right now? thank you very much!

```
import * as React from "react";
import Layout from '../components/MyLayout'
import Link from "next/link";
import {withRouter} from 'next/router'

interface IPostLinkProps{
  title:string
}

const PostLink = (props:IPostLinkProps) =>{
 return( 
    <li>
    <Link href={`/post?title=${props.title}`}>
      <a>{props.title}</a>
    </Link>
  </li>
 )
}

export default withRouter(function Blog(){
    return(
      <Layout>
        <h1> My Blog</h1>
          <ul>
              <PostLink title='hi'/>
              <PostLink title="HELP!"/>
              <PostLink title='hi'/>
          </ul>
      </Layout>
  )
})
```

index.js:1 Warning: the 'url' property is deprecated. https://err.sh/zeit/next.js/url-deprecated

Answer (score 0):

use useRouter may get help
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
interface IProps extends AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement> {
    label: string
}

export default function Link({children, href, label, ...rest}: IProps) {
    return <NextLink passHref {...{href}}>
        <a {...rest}>{label ?? children}</a>
    </NextLink>
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
<Link href='/' label='Home'/>
```

or

```
<Link href='/'>
  <span>Home</span>
</Link>
```